# Python Script send a ubuntu terminal command to a list

Tags: python, terminal, command

I have this command in Ubuntu:

```
bgpq3 -4 AS-YAHOO-JP-2 -m 24 -l Google
```

the output is a list of prefixes:

> ip prefix-list Google permit 14.137.224.0/19
>
> ip prefix-list Google permit 27.111.76.0/22
>
> ip prefix-list Google permit 27.121.128.0/17
>
> ip prefix-list Google permit 27.133.224.0/22
>
> ip prefix-list Google permit 27.133.240.0/22
>
> ip prefix-list Google permit 27.133.240.0/24
>
> ip prefix-list Google permit 27.133.241.0/24
>
> ip prefix-list Google permit 27.133.242.0/24
>
> ip prefix-list Google permit 27.133.243.0/24

how can i put the output to a list and use each line (as example send them to a database) I dont want to save them first to a file.txt

i am using this command but is does'nt help because the results are stored in a text file.

```
os.system("bgpq3 -4 AS-YAHOO-JP-2 -m 24 -l Google > list.txt")
```

Please help me figure this out!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, you could use subprocess module. This module replaces some older modules and functions. Official document is here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#module-subprocess

```
import subprocess
res = subprocess.Popen('bgpq3 -4 AS-YAHOO-JP-2 -m 24 -l Google', shell=True,
                       universal_newlines=True,
                       stdout=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()[0]

for line in res.split('\n'):
    print(line)
```